# What metadata, statistics, plans ALTER FUNCTION rebuilds?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-performance

The stored procedure uses user defined scalar function in its select statement. After some time SP starts performing poorly while no underlying data changed, when I recreate UDF, performance is back to normal.
The fact that recreating UDF (alter function, with no changes) resolves for short period performance issue makes me think that problem is not related to SP or UDF code. Any pointer to what gets changed when UDF recreated what might influence execution?
(actual query execution plan on both performance occasions looks the same)

Comment: Since performance is the real topic here I would consider rewriting this and getting rid of the scalar function entirely. They are notoriously horrible from a performance perspective.

Comment: Perhaps your procedure is using a bad plan. Altering the procedure would cause the plan cache to clear... though i'm not sure if altering the function which the plan references would cause this too. Check `sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats `

Comment: This kind of behavior typically shows up when either there is a huge skew in the amount of data being returned due to the parameters OR there are multiple execution paths and the plan is less than optimal for the current path.